# line 88; ParserError: expected ';' but got reserved keyword 'in' for (address user in orderBook[to ^^

Tags: ethereum, solidity

```
`function to calculate the current price of a listed token based on the available orders in     the order book
function getPrice(address token) public view returns (uint256) {
require(tokens\[token\], "Token is not listed");
uint256 totalAmount = 0;
uint256 totalPrice = 0;
for (address user in orderBook\[token\]) {
totalAmount = totalAmount.add(orderBook\[token\]\[user\]);
totalPrice = totalPrice.add(orderPrices\[token\]\[user\].mul(orderBook\[token\]\[user\]));
}
return totalPrice.div(totalAmount);
}`
```

6th line down, line 88 throwing this error line 88;
ParserError: expected ';' but got reserved keyword 'in' 88:19
88 | for (address user in orderBook[token] {
^^

haven't tried anything to fix it cause im not great at solidity

---

Answer (score 0):

In solidity you can't loop over an array like this:

```
for (element in array) {
    ...
}
```

but you have to do it like this:

```
for (uint256 i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
    // element = array[i];
    ...
}
```